# fade in and fade out in pure javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, fadein, fade, fadeout

Here I have a function that fades a square box with `id="box"` as soon as the page loads. I tried but failed to find out how to fade in the box again or simply how to fade in a box or an element with pure JavaScript not jQuery. 
Here is my code for `fadeOut()` function:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');

function fadeOut(elem, speed)
 {

 if(!elem.style.opacity)
 {
  elem.style.opacity = 1;
 }
 setInterval(function(){

 elem.style.opacity -= 0.02;
 
 }, speed /50);
}

fadeOut(box, 2000);
```

```css
#box
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Many thanks in advance to contributors. cheers

Comment: May be useful : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: It might help if you showed your failed attempt to make it fade in as well as your working code.

Comment: your interval is running forever, you need clearInterval when opacity is zero

Answer (score 11):

I'd suggest using CSS animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    0% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    0% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
.fadeOut {
  opacity:0;
  -moz-animation   : fadeout 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s linear;
  animation        : fadeout 1s linear;
}
```

You only need to add fadeOut class to the element

Answer (score 4):

If you want a pure JavaScript solution, you can use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3weg2zj1/1/

### HTML

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');

function fadeOutIn(elem, speed ) {

    if (!elem.style.opacity) {
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
    } // end if

    var outInterval = setInterval(function() {
        elem.style.opacity -= 0.02;
        if (elem.style.opacity <= 0) {
            clearInterval(outInterval);
            var inInterval = setInterval(function() {
                elem.style.opacity = Number(elem.style.opacity)+0.02;
                if (elem.style.opacity >= 1)
                    clearInterval(inInterval);
            }, speed/50 );
        } // end if
    }, speed/50 );

} // end fadeOut()

fadeOutIn(box, 2000 );
```

- in general, you have to capture the interval identifier returned by the `setInterval()` call so that you can cancel it later. Note that, in the above code, this involves closuring, both on `outInterval` and `inInterval`.
- for this specific code, you can test when opacity is at or below a lower threshold (I used zero), and then clear the existing interval process, and kick off a new one to reverse the animation.
- in the reverse interval process, you can increment the opacity, and then test against an upper threshold to decide when to clear the new interval process.
- I ran into a bizarre issue with trying to increment `elem.style.opacity`: the `+=` operator was refusing to work. After probably 10min of sitting and staring (and some experimentation), I finally figured out that `elem.style.opacity` is always being forced to be a string (perhaps *all* CSS-linked properties behave this way...), and so the `+` operator (and by extension the `+=` operator) was doing string concatenation, which, under the naive LoC of `elem.style.opacity += 0.02;`, was turning into `elem.style.opacity = elem.style.opacity+0.02;`, which, if we assume `elem.style.opacity` was at `'0.02'`, was turning into `elem.style.opacity = '0.02'+0.02;`, which was turning into `elem.style.opacity = '0.020.02';`, which the browser JavaScript engine (ahem) *generously* parses as `0.020` (because it requires a valid numeric value for the CSS opacity property!), which resulted in the opacity getting stuck at `0.02`. Holy crap! That's why I had to add the cast-to-number before doing the addition.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not really pure Js as it involves CSS animation like that of @Anarion but I included Js codes that is needed to do this on events like `onclick`. Check it out:

```js
function showHelloWorld(){
  var helloWorldElement = document.getElementById('hello-world');
  
  helloWorldElement.classList.remove('hide','fade-out');
  
  helloWorldElement.classList.add('fade-in')
  
}

function hideHelloWorld(){
   var helloWorldElement = document.getElementById('hello-world');
  helloWorldElement.classList.add('fade-out');
  helloWorldElement.classList.remove('fade-in');
  setTimeout(function(){
    helloWorldElement.classList.add('hide');
  },2000)  //Note that this interval matches the timing of CSS animation
}
```

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
}

#hello-world{ 
  font-size:36px;
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}

.fade-in{
  animation: 2s fadeIn;
}


.fade-out{
  animation: 2s fadeOut;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
  from{
    opacity:0;
  }
  
  to{
    opacity:1;
  }
}


@keyframes fadeOut{
  from{
    opacity:1;
  }
  
  to{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hello-world" class="hide">Hello World</div>
<br>
<button onclick="showHelloWorld()">Click Here To Fade In</button>

<button onclick="hideHelloWorld()">Click Here To Fade Out</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>pure javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> //begging of js
         let mydiv =document.createElement("div") //creating div
         let divtxt=window.document.createTextNode("hover me") //creating text node 
         mydiv.appendChild(divtxt) //now div with "hover me" text
         document.body.insertBefore(mydiv,document.body.childNodes[0])//insert before the script line in html
         mydiv.style.width="100px" //styling the div to 100px
         mydiv.style.fontSize="1.5em" //stylling the div with font Size
         mydiv.style.backgroundColor="yellow" //div has backgroundColor yellow
         let myp   =document.createElement("p") //create paragraph
         let ptxt=document.createTextNode("hello there") //create text node
         myp.appendChild(ptxt) //now p with "hello there" txt
         document.body.insertBefore(myp,document.body.childNodes[1]) //insert before script line in html
         let opacity=1; //begining with real work with opacity equal to 1 

          mydiv.onmouseenter=()=>{ //on mouseover main func that has 2 funcs one for reducing the opacity and another for terminate the process 
            mo=()=>{//child func to lower the opacity
            opacity-=.01 //lowering opacity by .01 every 10 mili sec
          myp.style.opacity=opacity//the actual fading happen here where the p is reduced
          }
       let x = setInterval(mo,10) //interval to make the func act as a loop and take x to clear it up later
        mo1=()=>{//secound func to terminate the first func
            clearInterval(x) //clear the first func after 980 mili sec
          myp.style.removeProperty("opacity")//removing opacity proberty 
          myp.style.display="none"//adding dispaly property and equall to none
         }
         setTimeout(mo1,980) //terminate the first func in 980 mili sec
          }
          mydiv.onmouseleave=()=>{ //second main func on mouseleave
            myp.style.removeProperty("display")//fisrt we got to remove dispaly none and raise the opacity
        mo=()=>{func to raise the opacity
          myp.style.removeProperty("display")//why i added it again just to make sure display property is removed
          opacity+=.01//increase opacity by .01
         myp.style.opacity=opacity//equalling the opacity of p  with the new opacity 
         }
        let y = setInterval(mo,10) //make the function to act as loop again 
       mo1=()=>{//sec func to terminate the first func
         clearInterval(y)//clearing the fisrt function

           myp.style.removeProperty("opacity")//remove opacity property
       }
        setTimeout(mo1,980)//wiaiting to stop the first func
      }
    </script>//end
</body>
</html>
```

pure javascript

Comment: Code only answers can almost always benefit from adding some explanation of how and why they work.