# Make fade in-out effect runs infinite (pure JS, not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, loops, fade, infinite

I was searching a script to make a div to fade in and out, and found this question [fade in and fade out in pure javascript without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662893/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript-without-jquery)

User *bgoldst* gave a nice solution that worked for me. But I would need the fade in-out to run in loop, not just once as stated by bgoldst's code. I'm totally new at JS and don't know how to get it to work, any suggestion?

EDIT: I have found a intermediate solution with Luke's suggestion and Kai's suggestions from [Pure JavaScript fade in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244338/pure-javascript-fade-in-function)

That is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById("foo");

    setInterval(function() {
        div.style.transition="opacity 1.5s";
        div.style.opacity=0;
    }, 1500);

    setInterval(function() {
        div.style.transition="opacity 1.5s";
        div.style.opacity=1;
    }, 3005);
</script>
```

However, the fade in/out effect doesn't  have a symmetric behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for that, no Javascript necessary. Just use the CSS animation property (set keyframes if you want, etc), and then set this property:

`animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Based on your comment, here is a Pen I made that will do what you want - you'll just have to change the animation from changing background color to making it fade. I hope that helps:

http://codepen.io/lukeschunk/pen/pyPpQO

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for answering. I was trying with keyframes initially, but I had problems using IE, so, I decided to try with JS.

Comment: You could use the javascript `setInterval` method. This will run something forever on a given interval. You'll want the interval value in milliseconds to match your needs depending on how long your animation is.

Comment: @b1919676 see the pen I just linked - I think it will set you on the  right track :)